# Drools 6 Rule Item Comparison

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Lets say I have an object type `MyObject` with member data `someValue` and `otherValue` and I insert two logical rules as follows:

```
Rule "Checks Some Value"
  when
    $myO : MyObject( someValue == Constants.someValueChecker )
  then
    insertLogical(new SomeValueChecked($myO));
end

Rule "Checks Other Value"
  when
    $myO : MyObject( otherValue == Constants.otherValueChecker )
  then 
    insertLogical(new OtherValueChecked($myO));
end
```

My question is, is there a way to verify whether these rules have fired for the same instance of MyObject? Also, is there a way to, given a particular instance of MyObject, know if these rules have fired for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify that both "some" and "other" value have been checked for the same object (and assuming that the reference to `MyObject` is kept in member `myObject`):

```
rule "some and other value"
when
    SomeValueChecked( $obj: myObject )
    OtherValueChecked( myObject == $obj )
then
  ...
end
```

And for checking whether both have fired for a particular instance of `MyObject`:

```
rule "some and other checked for green"
when
    $obj: MyObject( color == Colour.GREEN ) // or some other property
    SomeValueChecked( myObject == $obj )
    OtherValueChecked( myObject == $obj )
then
  ...
end
```

It should be obvious what is required to check for "some" or "other" alone.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the DRL/MVEL `==` operator checks for object equality, using the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, as opposed to the Java operator, which checks for the same **instance**. To check whether the rules have fired for the same **instance**, then it may be better to use `eval( myObject == $obj )` to force a Java reference check. Or are there better ways of doing that?